# Create Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) from XML-Tree

Tags: c++, optimization, xml

I've written a program that creates the (minimal unique) directed acyclic graph from the tree structure of an XML-document. The program prints a Bplex-Grammar to cout. I'm interested in all kinds of remarks, and especially performance optimization.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <libxml++/libxml++.h>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
#include <tr1/unordered_set>
#include <list>

// compile with:     g++ -Wall -g -Wno-deprecated `pkg-config --cflags libxml++-2.6` -o Dag dag.cpp `pkg-config --libs libxml++-2.6`


using namespace std;
using namespace tr1;
class TreeNode;
class TreeNodeHasher;
class TreeNodeEqualityTester;

typedef list<unsigned int> childrenList;
typedef unordered_map<unsigned int, unsigned int> GRAMMAR_MAP; 
typedef unordered_map<TreeNode*, unsigned int, TreeNodeHasher, TreeNodeEqualityTester> TREE_HASH_MAP;
typedef unordered_map<unsigned int, TreeNode*> RULES_MAP; 

class TreeNodeHasher
    : unary_function<TreeNode*, size_t>{
public:
    size_t operator()(TreeNode * pNode) const;
};

class TreeNodeEqualityTester
    : std::binary_function<TreeNode*, TreeNode*, bool>{
public:
    bool operator()(TreeNode *pNode1, TreeNode *pNode2) const;
};

class TreeNode{
    friend class TreeNodeHasher;
    friend class TreeNodeEqualityTester;

public:
    TreeNode(){;}
    TreeNode(string namePar, childrenList childrenListPar); 
    ~TreeNode(){;}

    string getName(){return this->name;}
    unsigned int getNumberOfChildren(){return this->numberOfChildren;}
    childrenList getKidsList(){return this->kidsList;}
    void incrementRefCount(){refCount++;}
    unsigned int getRefCount(){return refCount;}

private:
    string name;
    childrenList kidsList;
    unsigned int numberOfChildren;
    unsigned int refCount;
};


class MySaxParser : public xmlpp::SaxParser
{

public:
    MySaxParser(char * pFilePath, bool printProductionsPar);
    ~MySaxParser(void);
    void printProduction(TreeNode *pNode, unsigned int lhs, bool start);

protected:
  //overrides:
    virtual void on_end_document();
    virtual void on_start_element(const Glib::ustring& name,const AttributeList& properties);
    virtual void on_end_element(const Glib::ustring& name);

private:
    unsigned int leftHandSides;
    /**
      * For print use only.
      */
    unsigned int printedLeftHandSides;
    /**
      * The childrenStack is needed for parsing only.
      */
    stack< childrenList*> childrenStack;
    /**
      * The hash map of all trees encountered till now. TreeNode->unsigned int
      */
    TREE_HASH_MAP treeHashMap;
    /**
      * Only if a rule is the start production or encountered at least twice is it added to grammarMap.
      * It maps to the id of the TreeNode that has been found at least twice.
      */
    GRAMMAR_MAP grammarMap;
    /**
      * All unsigned int -> TreeNode are placed here. We need this for printing.
      */
    RULES_MAP rulesMap;

    /**
      * If true, we print the productions.
      */
    bool printProductions;

};

bool isNumber(string s){
    if(atoi(s.c_str()) > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

string toString(unsigned int number){
   stringstream ss;//create a stringstream
   ss << number;//add number to the stream
   return ss.str();//return a string with the contents of the stream
}

TreeNode::TreeNode(string namePar, childrenList childrenListPar):
    name(namePar), kidsList(childrenListPar), refCount(1){
    numberOfChildren = kidsList.size();
}

size_t TreeNodeHasher::operator()(TreeNode *pNode) const {
    size_t hash_value = 0;
    hash_value =  tr1::hash<string>()(pNode->name);
    boost::hash_combine(hash_value, pNode->kidsList);

    return hash_value;

}

bool TreeNodeEqualityTester::operator()(TreeNode *pNode1, TreeNode *pNode2) const{
    if(pNode1->name != pNode2->name){
        return false;
    }
    if(pNode1->numberOfChildren != pNode2->numberOfChildren){
        return false;
    }
    if(pNode1->kidsList != pNode2->kidsList){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

MySaxParser::MySaxParser(char * pFilePath, bool printProductionsPar) :
    xmlpp::SaxParser::SaxParser(), leftHandSides(2), printedLeftHandSides(2), printProductions(printProductionsPar){

    this->set_substitute_entities(true); //
    this->parse_file(pFilePath);

}

MySaxParser::~MySaxParser(void){
    BOOST_FOREACH(TREE_HASH_MAP::value_type i, treeHashMap){
        delete i.first;
    }
}

void MySaxParser::on_start_element(const Glib::ustring& name,const AttributeList& attributes){
    childrenList * chList = new childrenList();
    childrenStack.push(chList);
}

void MySaxParser::on_end_element(const Glib::ustring& name){
    unsigned int lhs = 0;
    string tmpname = name.raw();
    TreeNode * pTopNode = new TreeNode(tmpname, *childrenStack.top());
    delete childrenStack.top();
    childrenStack.pop();

    TREE_HASH_MAP::iterator it = treeHashMap.find(pTopNode);
    if(it == treeHashMap.end()){ // we've found the node for the first time
        if(childrenStack.size() == 0){ //root node
            treeHashMap[pTopNode] = 1;
            rulesMap[1] = pTopNode;
            grammarMap[1] = 1;
            if(printProductions){
                printProduction(pTopNode, 1, true); cout << endl;
            }
            return;
        }else{  //non-root node.
            treeHashMap[pTopNode] = leftHandSides;
            rulesMap[leftHandSides] = pTopNode;
        }
        lhs = leftHandSides;
        leftHandSides++;
    }
    else{
        delete pTopNode;
        lhs = it->second;
        it->first->incrementRefCount();
        if(it->first->getRefCount() == 2 && it->first->getNumberOfChildren() > 0 ){
            //we've found the rule twice, hence we add it to the grammarMap.
            grammarMap[lhs] = printedLeftHandSides;
            if(printProductions){
                printProduction(it->first, printedLeftHandSides, true); cout << endl;
            }
            printedLeftHandSides++;
        }
    }
    childrenList * chList = childrenStack.top();
    chList->push_back(lhs);
}


void MySaxParser::on_end_document(){
    cout << "size: " <<  treeHashMap.size() << endl;
}


void MySaxParser::printProduction(TreeNode *pNode, unsigned int lhs, bool start){

    if(start)
        cout << "A" << lhs << " -> ";
    cout << pNode->getName() ;
    if(pNode->getNumberOfChildren() > 0){
        unsigned int commaCounter = 1;
        TreeNode * pKidNode = 0;
        childrenList printList = pNode->getKidsList();
        childrenList::iterator chIt;
        GRAMMAR_MAP::iterator grIt;
        RULES_MAP::iterator ruIt;
        cout << "(" ;
        for(chIt = printList.begin(); chIt != printList.end(); chIt++){
            grIt = grammarMap.find(*chIt);
            if(grIt == grammarMap.end()){
                ruIt = rulesMap.find(*chIt);
                pKidNode = ruIt->second;
                printProduction(pKidNode, lhs, false);
            }
            else{
                cout << grIt->second;
            }
            if(commaCounter < pNode->getNumberOfChildren()){
                cout << ", ";
            }
            commaCounter++;
        }
        cout << ")" ;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]){

    if(argc < 2){
        cout << "Please add file. " << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    char * pFilePath = args[1];

    MySaxParser mySaxParser(pFilePath, true);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the semi-colon(';') here (it looks weird).

```
    TreeNode(){;}
```

The default destructor also does nothing.
If you are not doing anything use the one provided.

```
    ~TreeNode(){;}
```

You TreeNode methods are not `const correct`:
Mark methods that are non mutating as `const`. Return objects by reference to avoid a copy operation. If you don not want to give access to the underlying object then return a const reference to the object.

```
    string const&        getName()              const  {return this->name;}
    unsigned int         getNumberOfChildren()  const  {return this->numberOfChildren;}
    childrenList  const& getKidsList()          const  {return this->kidsList;}
    unsigned int         getRefCount()          const  {return refCount;}
```

Prefer pre-increment to post-increment.
For fundamental types there is no advantage for either. But for object types there is a difference as the default implementation requires an extra copy construction for post-increment. Even though you are using a fundamental type here that may not always be the case (future extensions may change things) in which case you have to go and change your post-increment to pre-increment to stay effecient. So it is a good habbit to get into.

```
    void                 incrementRefCount()           {refCount++;}
```

I am not convinced you is_Number() function works:

```
bool isNumber(string s){
    if(atoi(s.c_str()) > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

What happens for `isNumber("0")`

Also pass the string parameter by `const reference` This allows remporaries to be passed to the function (otherwise the above call will not work as the compiler can not construct a temporary std::string object and pass it to isNumber()).

Other issues:

- atoi() is relatively expensive.
- "12.34" is a number and would return true (I think) is that what you intended?

Your convert to string method:

```
string toString(unsigned int number){
   stringstream ss;//create a stringstream
   ss << number;//add number to the stream
   return ss.str();//return a string with the contents of the stream
}
```

Find a standard one they have been done a million times before.

```
boost::lexical_cast<std::string>()  // should work for you.
```

If you must do it yourself at least templatise it so that it works for anything:

```
template<typename T>
string toString(T const& number)
{
   stringstream ss;    //create a stringstream
   ss << number;       //add object to the stream
   return ss.str();    //return a string with the contents of the stream
}
```

One operation per line please. That includes the initalizer list:

```
TreeNode::TreeNode(string namePar, childrenList childrenListPar):
    // 
    // This is hard to read.
    name(namePar), kidsList(childrenListPar), refCount(1){
    numberOfChildren = kidsList.size();
}

// I like:

TreeNode::TreeNode(string namePar, childrenList childrenListPar)
    : name(namePar)
    , kidsList(childrenListPar)
    , numberOfChildren(kidsList.size())
    , refCount(1)
{}
```

Dislkie the use of this argument to call methods with:

```
this->set_substitute_entities(true); //
this->parse_file(pFilePath);
```

Why not just use:

```
set_substitute_entities(true);
parse_file(pFilePath);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You're right with the isNumber()-method, it actually isn't correct that way. I think I will find something better to replace it, but for that code it works because I don't use 0 anywhere. I worked in all the other suggestions (I also removed the toString()-method).